# Can I get some advice on a good setup for my leopard gecko?

Tags: leopard-geckos

I got a leopard gecko about 2-3 weeks ago, he seems healthy and happy, he runs about and seems okay.

Im just seeing lots of mixed reviews online about how to take care of them.

Like for example:
Some people say the leopard geckos need a UVB light to live (I have a UV Black light already)

And other people say it's un-needed and it makes the vivarium too hot.

Is there a "perfect" or atleast "By the books" definition and advice page or place where I can be sure Im taking care of my gecko.

Also I usually place my cage next to a window on the back side of my house, where no sunlight shines, just ambient light.

Is this a good thing? Or should I keep the blinds shut. My sister's baby leopard gecko is far from any window or natural area, and he seems to be depressed and unhappy, Constantly hiding in his house, never really coming out, my sis's gecko also fails to eat ANY form of waxworm/mealworm.

Can geckos really "hate" some types of food? My sis's gecko has been eating them fine about until a week ago.
Now he just eats crickets.

Comment: sorry if theres a lot of messy questions.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your sister's gecko is fine, leopard geckos randomly deciding not to eat a type of food is not uncommon at all. Because your sister's leopard gecko is a baby, it is common that it is hiding so often. Babies are typically more skittish and untrusting; but once it matures, it will probably ease out, although make sure it is not always in the dark, as leopard geckos need at least twelve hours of light and twelve hours of darkness.

Secondly, leopard geckos don't technically need UVB in my opinion (but I don't know much about it); but since you already have one, you should leave it on and if your leopard gecko uses it, it's great! Just make sure you are providing a heat mat or a deep heat projector.

Thirdly, placing your cage against a window might work, but you just have to be very careful that it doesn't heat up the enclosure like an oven.